# Efficient way to calculate inverse and determinant of $I + XX^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, determinant, inverse

### Problem

Let $A_{n \times n} = I_{n \times n} + XX^T$, where $X : n \times p$ matrix.

I would like to get the "computationally efficient"
 form of the following:

- $A^{-1}$
- $\mathrm{det}(A)$

By "computational efficiency", I mean something that minimizes computer time complexity (e.g. LU decomposition of $XX^T$).

---

### Try

So using [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity),

$$
A^{-1} = (I + XX^T)^{-1} = I - X (I + X^T X)^{-1} X^T
$$

but again

$$
(I + X^T X)^{-1} = I - X^T(I + XX^T)^{-1} X
$$

it gets circular.

And for the determinant, [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$
\mathrm{det}(I_n + XX^T) = \mathrm{det}(I_p+X^TX)
$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $p << n$, the $p \times p$ matrix $I_p + X^T X$ can be inverted directly (e.g. with Cholesky) to put in Woodbury's formula.

Comment: You did not mention if $\mathbf X$ has full rank.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Why do we need that condition?

Comment: For example, you can't invert $\mathbf X^\top\mathbf X$ if $\mathbf X$ is not full-rank.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Do I need to invert $X^TX$?

Comment: One of the methods I had in mind would need to, so it won't work in the rank deficient case. Well, no matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach.

1. Determinant is product of eigenvalues.
2. You can estimate singular values of $X$ : $\sigma_i$.
3. Then eigenvalues of $XX^T$ will be squares of those singular values
   (and pad with zeros if needed).

Now determinant will be $\prod_i (1+{\sigma_i}^2)$ because of Brauer's theorem I think.

This will be efficient if $n$ and $p$ are of very different sizes because the number of non-zero singular values will be maximally the smallest of those. Singular values can be estimated with power method for example.